# How to render particles from a FLIP fluid sim

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, flip

I've created these FLIP particles:

[image]

Instead of meshing them, I'd like to simply render them as halo particles (or instance geo on them if necessary). How can I go about that? Now when I hit render, all I see is the bounding domain.

Thanks!

Anson

Comment: Give the domain a transparent material. Go to the particle system settings and set it to render an object. As object choose for example an icosphere or any other object you add to the scene.